# react / redux-form: how to return promise from onSubmit?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to wrap my head around [redux](http://rackt.org/redux/), [react-redux](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) and [redux-form](http://erikras.github.io/redux-form/).

I have setup a store and added the reducer from redux-form. My form component looks like this:

**LoginForm**

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { login } from '../../actions/authActions'

const fields = ['username', 'password'];

class LoginForm extends Component {
    onSubmit (formData, dispatch) {
        dispatch(login(formData))
    }

    render() {
        const {
            fields: { username, password },
            handleSubmit,
            submitting
            } = this.props;

        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                <input type="username" placeholder="Username / Email address" {...username} />
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" {...password} />
                <input type="submit" disabled={submitting} value="Login" />
            </form>
        )
    }
}
LoginForm.propTypes = {
    fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    submitting: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'login',
    fields
})(LoginForm)
```

This works as expected, in [redux DevTools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools) I can see how the store is updated on form input and on submitting the form the `login` action creator dispatches the login actions.

I added the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware to the store and setup the action creator(s) for logging in as described in the [redux docs for Async Actions](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html):

**authActions.js**

```
import ApiClient from '../apiClient'

const apiClient = new ApiClient()

export const LOGIN_REQUEST = 'LOGIN_REQUEST'
function requestLogin(credentials) {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
        credentials
    }
}

export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'
function loginSuccess(authToken) {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        authToken
    }
}

export const LOGIN_FAILURE = 'LOGIN_FAILURE'
function loginFailure(error) {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
        error
    }
}

// thunk action creator returns a function
export function login(credentials) {
    return dispatch => {
        // update app state: requesting login
        dispatch(requestLogin(credentials))

        // try to log in
        apiClient.login(credentials)
            .then(authToken => dispatch(loginSuccess(authToken)))
            .catch(error => dispatch(loginFailure(error)))
    }
}
```

Again, in redux DevTools I can see that this works as expected. When `dispatch(login(formData))` is called in `onSubmit` in the LoginForm, first the `LOGIN_REQUEST` action is dispatched, followed by `LOGIN_SUCCESS` or `LOGIN_FAILURE`. `LOGIN_REQUEST` will add a property `state.auth.pending = true` to the store, `LOGIN_SUCCESS` and `LOGIN_FAILURE` will remove this property. (I know this might me something to use [reselect](https://github.com/rackt/reselect) for, but for now I want to keep it simple.

Now, in the redux-form docs I read that I can return a promise from `onSubmit` to update the form state (`submitting`, `error`). But I'm not sure what's the correct way to do this. `dispatch(login(formData))` returns `undefined`.

I could exchange the `state.auth.pending` flag in the store with a variable like `state.auth.status` with the values *requested*, *success* and *failure* (and again, I could probably use reselect or something alike for this).

I could then subscribe to the store in `onSubmit` and handle changes to `state.auth.status` like this:

```
// ...

class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    onSubmit (formData, dispatch) {
        const { store } = this.context
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
                const state = store.getState()
                const status = state.auth.status

                if (status === 'success' || status === 'failure') {
                    unsubscribe()
                    status === 'success' ? resolve() : reject(state.auth.error)
                }
            })
            dispatch(login(formData))
        }).bind(this)
    }

    // ...
}
// ...
LoginForm.contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

// ...
```

However, this solution doesn't feel good and I'm not sure if it will always work as expected when the app grows and more actions might be dispatched from other sources.

Another solution I have seen is moving the api call (which returns a promise) to `onSubmit`, but I would like to keep it seperated from the React component.

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> `dispatch(login(formData))` returns `undefined`

Based on [the docs for redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#composition):

> Any return value from the inner function will be available as the return value of `dispatch` itself.

So, you'd want something like

```
// thunk action creator returns a function
export function login(credentials) {
    return dispatch => {
        // update app state: requesting login
        dispatch(requestLogin(credentials))

        // try to log in
        apiClient.login(credentials)
            .then(authToken => dispatch(loginSuccess(authToken)))
            .catch(error => dispatch(loginFailure(error)))

        return promiseOfSomeSort;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to return a promise based on the apiClient errors?